# Что означает "недопи"?

Tags: значение-слов

> У него скорее всего слетел загрузчик с флешки, или где-то **недопи**.

[Источник](http://krikzz.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=74007691f52097d798123ebc5c6754b6&topic=3656.msg34496#msg34496)

Это просто ошибка или это слово имеет какое-нибудь значение?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, это ошибка. Никогда не видел такого слова. Возможно, там было слово "недописалось".

Comment: ddbug, это Вы могли бы указать в комментарии, но для ответа слишком иало информации.

Comment: @behemotus пока я не могу комментировать чужое, я в процессе первоначального накопления очков. Обещаю исправиться.

Comment: Ой. [Кажется, нашлось здесь](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=7516&p=30) Hо не вполне убедительно.

Answer (score 0):

В сети встречается достаточно часто. Слишком часто для просто опечатки, это какой-то сленг. А еще в сочетании с "перепи". Думаю, этимология понятна.
Вот точное значение для меня не совсем понятно, видимо просто "ерунда", "глупость"...

Как могло это слово с таким значением попасть в вашу фразу - не могу сказать. Может быть, и правда - по недоразумению.